# why did my hp officejet pro stop printing when I updated ubuntu 20.10

Tags: 20.10

hp officejet pro 8715 Ubuntu 20.10 computer software
have tried eithernet and usb neither works. If I ever get my printer operating again I have learned my lession, don't update to new software!!!

Comment: Why have you tagged Ubuntu 12.10 (or the 2012-October release), it's well past EOL and thus off-topic. How does it relate to your question?   I've assumed it was a typo and thus changed it to 20.10

Comment: We sometimes need to rebuild drivers to a new kernel. If you don't have the driver code look here https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/